How to access an app on a VPS using HTTPS without a domain name
I recently moved all of my dev environment to a Linux VPS from netcup, it's a simple linux machine, and I reconfigured the web application I'm currently working on. The app runs through apache inside a docker container on port 8080. I can access the app by typing the IP_OF_SERVER:PORT, example: 89.120.121.122:8080
However the web app rely on an authentication service (Auth0) that requires a secure origin, to be able to work, so I need to setup HTTPS. All the tutorials I found so far rely on having a domain name and then adding the SSL certificate. I want to know if there is a way for me to access the app using either the server IP and the port, or the server host (v123456789.quicksrv.de:8080) with HTTPS ? (i.e: https://v123456789.quicksrv.de:8080)
I'd really appreciate any resources that could help me with this.
Note: this is a dev environment and not a production one, so any workaround is fine with me, as long as I don't have to change the Dockerfile, since this is used by some other developers in my team.
Thanks
